# How can I write a tensorflow model that fits multiple linear equations?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'd like to write a model that fits multiple linear equations based on the input. I think I need a layer that estimates separating (or inflection) points, sets of parameters that correspond to each equation, and a layer that selects output based on the separating points. However, as I'm new to `machine learning`, I even don't know related keywords.

[image: Multiple linear equations based on input]

```
import tensorflow as tf

def build_and_compile_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=1),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3),
        # Need a kind of selection layer here.
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
    model.compile(
        loss='mean_absolute_error',
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1)
    )
    return model

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
y = tf.constant([10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 10, -10, -30, 0, 0, 0, 0])

model = build_and_compile_model()
model.fit(
    x,
    y,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=100,
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use machine learning to solve what seems like an ordinary least squares problem?

Comment: @paisanco This is a simplified problem for practice. I have a large dataset that can be divided into multiple subspaces, and fits to a multi-variable linear regression model within each subspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many lines you want to fit from your data, e.g. 3 from the picture, then you can have your model output 6 parameters. Those 6 parameters would be m1, b1, m2, b2, m3, b3, namely the slopes and y-axis intercepts for each line ( y = m1*x + b1, etc.).  Instead of tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) for your last layer, it would be tf.keras.layers.Dense(6). The inputs to the network are the (x,y) pairs, I suppose. Finally, you can mess around with the number of hidden layers (layers that are not the input and output layers - in your case, you have one: the tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)) and the number of nodes in each hidden layer, but you probably don't need more than one or two hidden layers.

Then, you would need to write a loss function, so that your neural network learns to output 6 parameters that match the parameters of the 3 lines. It could be something like loss = min(dist((x,y), line 1),dist((x,y), line 2),dist((x,y), line 3)). The dist function, i.e. the Euclidean shortest distance from a point to a line, can be derived from some simple linear algebra.